# How to change directory when user login to a specific directory in vsftpd

Tags: vsftpd

I am configuring vsftpd so that when user login it will redirect to a specified directory with read and write permissions in that directory. I have configured the following:

**Content of vsftpd.conf**

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd/userlist
userlist_deny=NO
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd/user_config_dir/
allow_writeable_chroot=YE
```

**Content of userlist**

```
ale
sunny
```

**Content of `/etc/vsftpd/userlist/ale`**

```
local_root=/var/www/ftp/ale
write_enable=YES
dirlist_enable=YES
download_enable=YES
```

**Output `ls -al /var/www/ftp/ale`**
[image]

When I login with user ale, I am redirected to `/` instead of `/var/www/ftp/ale` as expected.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the output of `ls -al /var/www/ftp/alex`

Comment: When you login via ftp check if this `/` is not actually `/var/www/ftp/alex`

Comment: have you restarted the `vsftpd` after changes?

Comment: I have restarted vsftp @αғsнιη

Comment: when i logged in it came / @Ro

Comment: Forget what is displayed, check what is inside!!! After login exec `ls`

Comment: ftp> ls
227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,28,139,108,56).
150 Here comes the directory listing.
226 Directory send OK.

Comment: So you see empty directory. Login via shell and create file with specific name. Then check via ftp if the file is there.

Comment: I uploaded a file and it worked. However when I create another user named leviz I get the error 500 OOPS: cannot change directory:/var/www/ftp/test

Comment: THis is another question, please use this link https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 1):

So the answer is: work as design.

The reason is first you have set the root directory for this user:

```
local_root=/var/www/ftp/ale
```

then you define to `chroot` local users;

```
chroot_local_user=YES
```

so when the user login (via `ftp`) it is directed to directory `/var/www/ftp/ale` which is mapped from `ftp` daemon as root (`/`). And you can't see upper directories